# Visual Basic - Multiple Choice Test

Tags: vb.net

I am really new to visual studio and I also want to learn to make a test like this but so far I managed to make 2 questions and 4 answers each. What I want to know is 
how do I check if the good answer is checked for more than 2 questions.
how do I make button5 to change text to do what button1 does, so instead of having two buttons from the start, just one that changes.

My code so far is :

```
Public Class Test1
    Dim question(2, 5) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 2
    Private Sub Test1_Load()
        question(1, 0) = "2+2="
        question(1, 1) = "1"
        question(1, 2) = "2"
        question(1, 3) = "3"
        question(1, 4) = "4"
        question(2, 0) = "How old are you?"
        question(2, 1) = "12"
        question(2, 2) = "13"
        question(2, 3) = "17"
        question(2, 4) = "18"
        Label1.Text = question(i - 1, 0)
        nr1.Text = question(i - 1, 1)
        nr2.Text = question(i - 1, 2)
        nr3.Text = question(i - 1, 3)
        nr4.Text = question(i - 1, 4)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Test1_Load()
        Button5.Hide()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If i = 2 AndAlso nr4.Checked = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Good job. You have one point")
        ElseIf i = 2 AndAlso nr4.Checked = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry. You are wrong")
        ElseIf i = 3 AndAlso nr4.Checked Then
            MessageBox.Show("Good job. Another point")
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Test1_Load()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Tip: That is not VB6 code.

Comment: Your `question`array should contain the value for the correct answer so you can easily compare it to the selected value instead of hard coding the comparison for every single question.

Comment: could use a variable to store if they answered correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable to store if the first answer was correct like

```
Dim correctAnswers = 0
```

and then in your button click method,

```
If i = 2 AndAlso nr4.Checked = True Then
    correctAnswers+= 1 'increment correctAnswers by 1
    MessageBox.Show("Good job. You have one point")
ElseIf i = 2 AndAlso nr4.Checked = False Then
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry. You are wrong")
ElseIf i = 3 AndAlso nr4.Checked Then
    correctAnswers += 1 'increment correctAnswers by 1
    MessageBox.Show("Good job. Another point")
End If
i = i + 1
Test1_Load()
```

You could also add something like

```
If i > 3 Then 'if i > 3, then you have run out of questions
    MessageBox.Show("That's the end of the test. You answered " + correctAnswers.ToString() + " questions correctly.")
Else 'if i < 3, then there are still questions to answer
    'Put the rest of your code here
End If
```

in your button click method.

Comment: I tried your method with if i>3 but when I run it and at the last question I put the wrong answer, all the text goes blank and nothing happens...I don't understand why it jumps over that condition

Comment: If i > 3 is only checked after you click the button again. If you want it to show something for the wrong answer on the last question, you need to handle that case the same way that you did for the first question.

Comment: yeah, i got it all figured it out after all. Thank you for all btw, really helped me a lot.